# Why doesn't my .js.erb seem to have access to methods defined in my Pages Helper?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a page, `poweroutput.html.erb`, that shows the power output of a customer's solar power system for a particular date. When they input a different date, I want them to see different output, but without having to reload the page. On my page I have some javascript as well as a form (for submitting the date for which a user would like to see the power output) as follows:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <%= render "pages/poweroutputscript" %>  # renders a partial containing all my js
  </script>
</head>

# a form is here on this page too
```

My page's controller action is currently as follows:

```
def poweroutput      
  # some code 

  if request.xhr?
    @date = params[:dt]         # dt is posted when form is submitted
  else 
    @date = Time.now.getlocal.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
    format.js { render :action "pages/poweroutput.js.erb" }
  end
end
```

And poweroutput.js.erb is as follows:

```
$("script").replaceWith("<script><%= escape_javascript render "pages/poweroutputscript" %></script>");
```

There is a method in my Pages Helper called `get_eac_day` which is called in my _poweroutputscript.html.erb with <%= get_eac_day %>. It works fine when the page is first loaded. But for some reason when the partial is rendered on javascript request, get_eac_day returns nil. It's as if the partial does not have access to my Pages Helper methods all of a sudden. I can see that it has access to the variables defined in my controller action (like @date). Is there some sort of special include statement that I may be missing? Or something else altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could pass the return value of `get_eac_day` to your partial like so:

```
<%= render "pages/poweroutputscript", :ged => get_eac_day %>
```

and then edit your _poweroutputscript.html.erb like so:

```
<%= ged %>
```

Comment: Wow sorry. Turns out i just made a dumb logical error in my pages helper function and that's why it was returning nil. I am, however, going to use this method of just defining whatever I need in my controller action as in @ged = get_eac_day and a corresponding <%= @ged %> in my partial as it is more elegant than what I had happening.